# Splitting 4K output to be displayed on 4x1080p screens without adding a gfx card

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, 4k-resolution, 1080p

How can a 4K image from a single output be displayed on four tiled 1080p screens

E.g. monitor 1 showing top left part of the 4k output, screen 2 showing top right part of the 4k output...

```
_____________________
|    1    |    2    |
|_________|_________|
|    3    |    4    |
|_________|_________|
```

I'm looking for hardware solutions like an AV amp (I don't know what this feature would be called) or some smart DisplayPort adapter splitter.